# Is keepalived + VIP needed for DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, high-availability

I have two dns servers running powerdns, they are using native replication, ie, they are hitting an HA postgres cluster.

When creating a new server, I specify the IPs of the two DNS servers in `dns-nameservers` in `/etc/network/interfaces` of the new server.

So far, this all works great.

I'm guessing that is all that is needed for DNS to be HA? I don't need keepalived or a VIP?

Or say, a pool of DNS servers behind haproxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your present config is fine for ensuring availability; the benefit of adding a VIP and using keepalived, haproxy, or an anycast config would be to minimize the delay from a timeout if the first-listed server were unavailable.

Comment: I do not believe it's recommended to configure DNS servers with keepalived or HAProxy. Anycast could be an option but just listing two IP addresses for your DNS servers is just the way it works.

Comment: @Tom Unfortunately it doesn't "just work" due to limitations in how IP address failover is implemented in stub resolver libraries. Depending on the size and criticality of the production environment, it is in fact necessary to maximize the uptime of those IP addresses. If a software load balancer is used, I would recommend a DNS focused implementation such as [dnsdist](https://dnsdist.org/).

Comment: Could you shed some light on that issue with stub resolver libraries or do you have a lick to an article on that issue? I didn't know about dnsdist so I will read up on that. Thanks!